# Debugging a func inside a static comparer class

Tags: c#, .net-core, func

I'm doing some comparisons for certain thing between different instances of two objects. Since those comparisons are sequential (if comparison A == 0, we go to comparison B, if comparison B == 0 we go to comparison C, and so on until we return a -1 or a 1) and I didn't want to put a lot of ifs, I thought about doing this:

```
public static class TStatsComparer
{
    public static int Compare(TStats? t1, TStats? other)
    {
        Func<TStats, TStats, int>[] comparisonRules = new Func<TStats, TStats, int>[]
            {
                (t1, t2) => CompareA(t1, t2),
                (t1, t2) => CompareB(t1, t2),
                (t1, t2) => CompareC(t1, t2),
                (t1, t2) => CompareD(t1, t2),
                (t1, t2) => CompareE(t1, t2),
            };

        int result = comparisonRules.Select(method => method(t1, other))
                            .FirstOrDefault(result => result != 0);

        return result;
}
```

where `CompareA` (or B, or C...) is a method like

```
static int CompareA(TStats? t1, TStats? other)
{
    int result = 0;
    // ...
    // We do the comparison and store it in result
    // result values could be 0,1 or -1

    return result;
}
```

and the compared class

```
public class TStats : IComparable<TStats>
{
    //...

    public int CompareTo(TStats? other)
    {
        return TStatsComparer.Compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

So it gets the first comparison that returns something different than 0 and returns that. It works as intended, but the thing here is that I can't debug it from Visual Studio. If I put a break point inside `CompareA` method, for example, it says that

> Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)

It still works, though, but that's it, I can't debug it.

If I remove the `Func<>` thing and call the `CompareA/B/C` methods directly and sequentially, I can debug it normally.

Am I doing something big of a mistake using the comparer like that?

Even if the func is executed in other thread or some sort of anonymous method, shouldn't I be able to debug the inside methods?

Comment: Do you mean you put a breakpoint on the line `(t1, t2) => CompareA(t1, t2)`?

Comment: @Sweeper Inside the CompareA method body, or CompareB/C/D...

Comment: Is it related to this reported issue? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62232

Comment: @AstridE. Mmmm, it seems so, since the code from that issue's op is similar to mine. Put that as an answer if you want and if nobody says anything else, I'll marked as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @xecollons No problem! Seems like a very particular scenario. Have you tried debugging it in e.g. Rider (from JetBrains)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could try *collecting the comparison rules in a list rather than an array*.

I.e. when implementing your code snippet, changing

```
var comparisonRules = new Func<TStats, TStats, int>[]
{
    ...
};
```

to

```
var comparisonRules = new List<Func<TStats, TStats, int>>
{
    ...
};
```

may allow the debugger to hit the breakpoints inside the `Compare*()` methods.

Doing this change worked for me in **Visual Studio 22, Windows 11, targeting .NET 6**.

---

*Why* you experience the debugging deviation, I really don't know.

**An issue that looks very similar to your scenario was reported on GitHub in November 2021:**
[Debugger can't step into a function in a given situation with Linq #62232](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62232)

The issue reporter claims that the issue occurs in VS Code and Visual Studio (2022) on Windows 10 when using .NET 6; whereas for .NET 5 and .NET Framework 4.8, the issue does not occur.

*As of September 2023, the issue is still open.*

The code snippet that is provided for recreation in is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new[] { "1", "4", "h", "l1", "7" };
    var parsedList = list.Select(item => DoSomething(item)).Where(item => item == 1).ToList();
}

public static int DoSomething<T>(T input)
{
    return 1;
}
```

along with the following comment:

> Just place a breakpoint in DoSomething and run.
>
> VS Goes into break mode: ("Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).") - stepping seems still to work, no other error is shown
>
> VS Code : the callstack shows: "Error processing stackTrace request. Unknown Error 0x80131c49" - and seems to be completely stuck

Comment: As for workaround, at least something that worked for me, is to add a .ToList to the query after the Where.

Comment: @xecollons Hmm. I played a little bit around with it, and I also noticed [jeremybparagon's comment in their answer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62232#issuecomment-1222929111): _One workaround that will likely get me by is to add a call to `ToList()` before the call to Where_. I tried simply changing the datatype of `comparisonRules` from `Func<TStats, TStats, int>[]` to `List<Func<TStats, TStats, int>>` to see if that made any difference, and the breakpoint inside the relevant `Compare*` methods are in fact being hit now. Does simply changing the datatype work for you?